# Monaco editor copy/cut/paste action

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I'm using [monaco editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor) for my project and I can be able to emit editor events for undo/redo actions like so:

```
editor.getModel().redo();
editor.getModel().undo();
```

This is a very common editor, so I think there should be cut/copy/pase actions also, but unfortunately, I don't see similar actions like editor.getModel().cut.. e.t.c.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use native browser events along with your editor and make sure your editor has 'focus' for those actions:

```
editor.focus();
document.execCommand('cut'); // copy paste, e.t.c
```

Answer (score 5):

You can trigger editor actions to copy/paste:

```
editorInstance.trigger('source','editor.action.clipboardCopyAction');
editorInstance.trigger('source','editor.action.clipboardPasteAction');
```

Actions available can be listed with: `editorInstance.getActions().map(a => a.id)`

I still haven't figured out what effect the first argument to trigger has, so I have simply provided a string that suggests what triggered the action.

Comment: this copies one line only. how to copy the whole document string?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use modern APIs, then you can use the Clipboard API as follows

For cut:

```
function cutOrCopy(editor:monaco.editor.IStandaloneEditor, isCut:boolean) {
  editor.focus();
  // Get the current selection in the editor.
  const selection = editor.getSelection();
  if (!selection || selection.isEmpty()) {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText("");
    return;
  }

  // Get the text from that selection.
  const data = editor.getModel()?.getValueInRange(selection);

  // Set the clipboard contents.
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(data || "");

  if (isCut) {
    // This is a cut operation, so replace the selection with an empty string.
    editor.executeEdits("clipboard", [{
      range: selection,
      text: "",
      forceMoveMarkers: true,
    }]);
  }
}
```

And likewise for paste

```
async function paste(editor:monaco.editor.IStandaloneEditor) {
  editor.focus();
  // Get the current clipboard contents
  const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();

  // Get the current selection in the editor.
  const selection = editor.getSelection();
  if (!selection) {
    return;
  }

  // Replace the current contents with the text from the clipboard.
  editor.executeEdits("clipboard", [{
    range: selection,
    text: text,
    forceMoveMarkers: true,
  }]);
}
```